# David tool online not converting most genes

Tags: r, bioconductor, sequence-annotation, identifiers, geoquery

I'm using DAVID tool online, in order to perform functional annotation chart. I extracted the most relevant genes from a dataset (GSE73304), but have the problem that DAVID is not able to understand the most part.

I tried to put my 250 most relevant genes, such as

```
A_33_P3230339
A_21_P0014879
A_23_P373568
A_23_P206371
```

into David, using as identifier "AGILENT_ID", as I found in the website. However, David is able to recognize just 89 of them (which are classified correctly as "homo sapiens"). I have the same problem if I try to do the gene_id conversion.

This might be not a David's problem, since I tried also on R withoud good results.

If someone knows the reason of this issue and how to solve it, it would be really appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may find annotation here : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GPL17077

Comment: First try converting your Agilent probe IDs to Entrez ID or Gene Symbols and then run functional annotation analysis. You also need to understand that Gene Symbols or Entrez IDs are not available for all probe IDs.